# How to create image from a 2d array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

I have a program which reads data from a text or grid file and computes gravitational data. The results are negative doubles as -4.85734895892 etc. This array generally will be a square array but program can handle rectangular form as well. What I want to do is to create a contour map but honestly I've never written anything like it. I always wrote algorithms that compute data.

A bitmap image is sufficient for now since it's only necessary for initial prospection.

What I thought was this:
Let's say I have 101 to 101 array. I will find min and max values and find the increment number. Then turn these numbers to visual spectrum from green to red, then create a basic bitmap. Problem is that as far as I get it, I need to convert my 2d double array to byte array and use rbg as a visual representation. I'm kind of lost here.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3 and I'm also writing the same program with mono. Though it's doing the same thing only without user interface.

Comment: To go from an array of data to an image, you need an algorithm. This is too broad to explain in an answer, and libraries exist that already contain this algorithm. Search the web for charting and graphing libraries.

Comment: After reading your reply, I've searched for graphing libraries and decided to use oxyplot and it was rather easy to implement. I haven't got into it as much as I'd like yet but I guess it doesn't have support for mono which is a shame. Running it on multiple os would be way better.